# Travel from Arabba Ski Region to Venice

Tags: public-transport, italy, venice

I will be in Arabba from 2/28/15 to 3/7/15 and would like to take a day to do some sightseeing in Venice.  What is the easiest way to get around without having to rent a car?

Comment: How are you getting to Arabba in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

**The best, and easiest, way into Venice IMHO is via train to Venezia Santa Lucia station.** [Arabba however doesn't have a train station](http://www.arabba.it/en/information/where-we-are/6-0.html). There are several ways to get to the train stations in the neighbouring cities, spanning various price ranges.

Bottom line is, logistics to/from these ski resorts are everything but easy.

### Taxi it to Bolzano

You could get a taxi to the closest important stations, which are:

```
- Stazione di Belluno km 70
- Stazione di Brunico km 50
- Stazione di Bolzano km 75
```

Considering the distances, this could turn out to be fairly expensive. Moreover, there are no direct trains from, say Bolzano, to Venice. The connections run though Verona.

### Bus it to Belluno

There is a bus from Arabba to Belluno, [whose timetable you can find here](http://www.arabba.it/files/content/1003466_55461_2_0/linea-corvara-arabba-belluno.pdf) (thanks to [@ptityeti](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13052/ptityeti)). From Belluno there are several train connections to Venice, which pass through either Castelfranco Veneto or Conegliano.

### Dolomiti Ski Shuttle

Another option is the [Dolomiti Ski Shuttle](http://dolomitistars.dolomiti.org/index.cfm/transfer-eng/), which runs from Arabba to Venezia Mestre station, from which you can get a train into Venice. This would be the easiest option, however the shuttle runs only on weekends so you will have only two options to visit Venice: either fro, 28th February to 1st March, or on the 7th of March (which is your departure date).

A tentative shuttle booking from Arabba to Venezia Mestre for the following dates:

- Arrival trip:   28 February 2015 departure time 06:15
- Departure trip:  1 March 2015  departure time 17:00

Yields a cost per person of 45`EUR`.

Comment: There is a bus to Belluno: http://www.arabba.it/files/content/1003466_55461_2_0/linea-corvara-arabba-belluno.pdf